# USB Host or Serial capability in Android Phones

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I am attempting to compile a list of Android phones which can be put into USB Host mode or have serial capability.

Are there any phones, other than what is listed here that have either USB Host/USB OTG or Serial capability?

Serial:

HTC Dream
HTC Magic
HTC Hero
HTC/Google Nexus One

USB:

Motorola Droid
Nexus One
Galaxy Nexus

Comment: Do you have a question or do you only want to inform us about what you are doing? ;-)

Comment: I know this post was almost a year ago, but I can add 2 more to the list: OTG/HOST CAPABLE: Motorola Razr Maxx HD NOT host capable: Motorola Razr Maxx I have been looking for a phone to interface with an Arduino for a specific application.

Comment: @Nick this question is indeed a bit out of date.  I believe most of the newer phones coming out are 4.0 and above should support USB OTG.  Of the small sample I've tested with thus far, all have worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the serial capability on the HTC phones requires a kernel recompile, though the code is there and only needs to be enabled in the kernel config.  For the MSM7201 based phones (G1/Magic/Hero) USB host is also a possibility with a kernel recompile after applying an unofficial patch.

Of everything listed, I think USB host on the droid is the only capability available on a device as delivered to consumers, everything else requiring rooting and reflashing.

There's a high probability of other vendor's devices using the same processor as the listed ones to also have these capabilities - especially for USB, maybe less so for serial.

Comment: I've rooted an Android phone, but kept the factory firmware on there.  Is there much extra work involved in upgrading your phone with the modified kernel/android package?

Comment: yes, especially if you aren't just installing images created by someone else, but have to compile them and test them yourself (testing is hard because you lose adb-over-usb when you go to host mode)

Comment: Sounds dreadful :) I've purchased an Archos 23 "tablet"  which I plan to use for some basic USB HID testing on Android.